Operator-form correspondence without lower semiboundedness
When dealing with a normal unbounded operator $A$, it is often useful to frame questions about the operator in terms of questions about the associated form $\omega,$ which has domain $D(|A|^{1/2})$ and is defined in terms of the spectral decomposition of $A$ by
$$\omega(x, y) = \int \lambda \langle dE(\lambda) x, y \rangle.$$
Simply from the fact that $A$ is normal, one can show e.g. that this is expressed in terms of the polar decomposition $A = U |A|$ as
$$\omega(x, y) = \langle U |A|^{1/2} x, |A|^{1/2} y\rangle,$$
and that the complex conjugate of $\omega_A(x,y)$ is the form $\omega_{A^*}(y, x).$
In nearly every text I have read about the forms associated with operators, the author immediately restricts attention to lower semibounded self-adjoint operators, for which the associated forms are lower semibounded as well. The author then defines a notion of closure for forms which is implied by closure of the self-adjoint operator, and shows that any closed lower semibounded self-adjoint form gives rise to an associated self-adjoint operator.
I have found a few sources going beyond this paradigm, where similar things are done for general normal operators for which the self-adjoint part is lower semibounded. What I haven't seen, however, is any explanation for why lower semiboundedness is essential. It is used in all of the proofs, but I am having trouble understanding why it is a fundamental piece of the puzzle in the operator-form correspondence. Certainly a non-lower-semibounded self-adjoint operator gives rise to a form; are there robust theorems explaining when a non-lower-semibounded form gives rise to an associated operator?
